# Java decoupling issue

Tags: java

am new to Java. I am trying to decouple the Responder class from the WeatherSystem Class. But I get an error at Public NewResponder in the Responder class (invalid method declaration; return type required), I am really stuck at this point. I have tried changing all the class points at NewResponder and responder but can't rectify it. Could anyone point out why I am getting this issue, please?
(I also have InputReader class but that's not included below).

***WeatherSystem Class***

```
        import java.util.HashSet;

        public class WeatherSystem
        {
        private InputReader reader;
        private NewResponder responder;

        public WeatherSystem(NewResponder responder) 
        {
        reader = new InputReader();
        this.responder = new Responder();
        }
         public void start()
         {
         boolean finished = false;

         printWelcome();

        while(!finished) {
        HashSet<String> input = reader.getInput();

        if(input.contains("exit")) {
            finished = true;
        }
        else {
            String response = this.responder.generateResponse(input);
            System.out.println(response);
        }
      }
     printGoodbye();
```

.............................................

***Class Responder***

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Random;
    import WeatherSystem.NewResponder

    public class Responder implements NewResponder 
    {

     private HashMap<String, String> responseMap;
     private ArrayList<String> defaultResponses;
     private Random randomGenerator;

    public NewResponder()
    {
    responseMap = new HashMap<>();
    defaultResponses = new ArrayList<>();
    fillResponseMap();
    fillDefaultResponses();
    randomGenerator = new Random();
    }


    public String generateResponse(HashSet<String> words)
    {
    for (String word : words) {
        String response = this.responseMap.get(word);
        if(response != null) {
            return response;
        }
    }
    return pickDefaultResponse();
```

....................................................

Comment: Change `public NewResponder` to `public Responder`

Comment: The name of the constructor has to match the name of the class.  Change `public NewResponder()` to `public Responder()`.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with "decoupling"? Your error has nothing to do with this.

Comment: First you need to read about java code convention, and problem could be resolved by yourself.

Comment: If I change public NewResponder to Responder I get issues with: import WeatherSystem.NewResponder - package WeatherSystem does not exist. and public class Responder implements NewResponder  - cannot find symbol class NewResponder.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to check whether you need interface `NewResponder` inside `WeatherSystem`. Which you are implementing in `Responder` class with wrong constructor name.